# Reflexive pronoun in relative clause

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which sentence is grammatically correct? And is the other acceptable or just never used in daily conversation?
1. I am someone who loves himself. 
2. I am someone who loves myself.

Answer (score 0):

There must be the subject-object correspondence in this clause.
The verb form is 3rd person singular. So the object must be 'himself, herself or oneself'. The choice depends on the sex of the subject referent (if it is important or known).

Answer (score 0):

"Reflexive" traces its origin to mediaeval Latin, reflexus meaning turning back or reflecting.When the subject of a verb is also the object we use a reflexive pronoun, and this is central to our understanding about the use of reflexive pronoun in objective position be it direct or indirect. Our example sentence is:-

★ I am someone who loves himself (myself).

In this relative clause, 'someone' is the antecedent of 'who' which is the subject of the relative clause , thus making the use of HIMSELF mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) The answer in one sentence**

The sentence * *I am someone who loves myself* is ungrammatical in English.

> (1) good: **I am someone who loves himself**.
>
> (2) ungrammatical: * **I am someone who loves myself**.

**(2) Explanation: Binding requirements of *myself***

Reflexive anaphors must be co-referential with (i) a **suitable** and (ii) **local** antecedent.

Here, *myself* must find a co-referential antecedent within its local clause *who loves myself*, shown as a bracketed constituent in (3).

> (3)* **... someone [**<sub>local clause</sub> ***who<sub>i</sub>* loves *myself<sub>i</sub>*]**.

The only possible antecedent for *myself* in that clause is the subject, *who*, which in turn is a placeholder for, or understood to refer to, *someone*, from the higher clause. However, the anaphor *myself* requires a first person singular subject. The potential antecedent *who*, referring to *someone*, is not a first persons singular subject. Therefore ***who* cannot function as a suitable antecedent for *myself***.

Note that if we change the antecedent to a first person singular item, binding of *myself* becomes more acceptable (even though some native speakers never like co-reference between *myself* and a relative pronoun) and the whole sentence becomes grammatical. This is illustrated in (4).

> (4) **It wasn't me [**<sub>local clause</sub> ***who<sub>i</sub>* called *myself<sub>i</sub>* a legend]**.

One might think that there is another potential antecedent for *myself*, namely the first person singluar personal pronoun *I*, in the higher clause. The presence of *I* is sketched in (5).

> (5)* ***I<sub>i</sub>* am ... [**<sub>local clause</sub> **... loves *myself<sub>i</sub>*]**.

However, this antecedent is too far away from *myself* to allow co-reference. The pronoun *I* is not within the local clause of *myself* but outside of it. Hence, ***I* cannot function as a local antecedent for *myself***.

Note that if *I* is placed inside of the local clause of *myself*, binding of *myself* becomes acceptable and the whole sentence grammatical. This is shown in (6).

> (6) **Mary is someone  [**<sub>local clause</sub> **who *I<sub>i</sub>* presented *myself<sub>i</sub>* to _ ]**.

Thus, no matter whether one attempts to pick *who* or *I* as the antecedent, the reflexive anaphor *myself* cannot be co-referential with it and hence remains unbound. This results in the ungrammaticality of the sentence.

The binding requirements of reflexive anaophors like *myself* are quite well understood in formal syntax. For some more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_(linguistics)).